# Sending GET requests to same page with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Lets say there is a php code

page.php

```
<a href="page.php?pid=1" id="1">Product 1</a>
<a href="page.php?pid=2" id="2">Product 2</a>

<?php 
$_GET['pid'];
if(!isset($_GET['pid'])){
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['pid']);
    $stmt->execute();
?>
<table>
    <tr><td>*show products code*</td></tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Now what I'm thinking that is there any solution that when I click on anchor tags, the page wouldn't refresh instead it stays there and send value to the `$_GET['pid'];`

A bit of jquery ajax part I thought of is this

```
$('a').click(function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'page.php',
        method: 'GET',
        data: $(this).attr('id').serialize(),
    });
});
```

It didn't work and I do not fully understand how would I send data to `$_GET['pid']`

Any help with a bit of explanation would gladly help me a lot...

Comment: It didn't work how? Internet is full of manuals explaining working with ajax.

Comment: `$(this).attr('id').serialize(),` makes no sense The attr() returns a string and a string does not have serialize

Comment: `data` option only make sense with `POST` requests. `GET` data should be passed with URL.

Comment: Try change ajax url in js  `url: "page.php?pid=" + $(this).attr('id'),`

Comment: @epascarello sorry my mistake, I wrote the code there on stackoverflow editor. My bad :(

Comment: @korchemkin that seems to be a fair solution! Should I add preventDefault(); to prevent page from refreshing upon achor tag click?

Comment: Yes, `event.preventDefault();` should be stop following a link

Comment: I don't get it. You send an AJAX request to the page you want to show and what to you do with the result ? Replace the whole loaded DOM with the HTML from the AJAX response ? Also the condition in your `if` statement should lose the `!` if you're gonna use `$_GET['pid']` you should make sure it **IS** set not the opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
$('a').click(function(event){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'page.php?pid=' + $(this).attr('id'),
      method: 'GET'
   });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

or

```
$('a').click(function(event){
   $.ajax({
     url: $(this).attr('href'),
     method: 'GET'
   });
   event.preventDefault();
 });
```

PS  I recommend codestyle like this, because js interpreter puts the ";":